# How do I pass and retrieve memory stream from my Application to/from DLL?

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-7

Suppose I have a `TMemoryStream` I need to pass to my DLL and get back `TMemoryStream` (Bitmap stream) from the DLL.

I was thinking my DLL would have:

```
procedure Process(
  InBuff: Pointer; 
  InBuffSize: Integer; 
  var OutBuff: Pointer; 
  var OutBuffSize: Integer
); stdcall;
```

The `InBuff` is easy (I think). I pass `TMemoryStream.Memory` and `TMemoryStream.Size`.

Question is how do I allocate the `OutBuff` in the DLL, and the caller application can convert it back to `TMemoryStream` and later free that memory (by the caller application)?

The caller will use dynamic `LoadLibrary`/`FreeLibrary` each DLL call.

I would very much like a sample code. Hope I'm not being too rude.

Note 1: The caller application dose not know the output size, and assume it can not specify a MAX buff size.

Note 2: I am not sure about my DLL signature. Please forgive me if I did it wrong. I am Looking for a pattern that will work well (maybe not only for Delphi but for C++/C# Caller as well = Bonus for me)

Comment: @Remy Please don't change the question. It states, *"Question is how do I allocate the OutBuff in the DLL"* which is clear. The intent is as the question currently is, as it was before anyone answered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm not the one who changed the code in the question. You did, I simply reverted it back to the original. If the intent of the question did not match the actual code provided, the OP should have fixed the question accordingly. If there is a bug in the code, point it out in a comment or answer, don't blindly assume that any code you make is what the OP is actually using in their project.

Comment: @Remy That's not how this site works. The edit I made was valid.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Sorry. I initially was not sure that the DLL signature was correct in the first place. I did not know about the `var` Pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two obvious options, assuming the callee is to allocate the memory:

**1. Use a shared heap**

For instance you can use the COM heap. In the callee your write:

```
OutBuffSize := ...; // you know what this value is
OutBuff := CoTaskMemAlloc(OutBuffSize);
// populate the buffer
```

The caller destroys this with `CoTaskMemFree`. You can use `LocalAlloc`, or `HeapAlloc` if you prefer, it doesn't really matter.

**2. Use the callee's heap and export a deallocator**

Here you use the native heap of the callee:

```
OutBuffSize := ...; // you know what this value is
GetMem(OutBuff, OutBuffSize);
// populate the buffer
```

You also need to export a deallocator:

```
procedure DeallocateMemory(Ptr: Pointer); stdcall;
begin
  FreeMem(Ptr);
end;
```

---

Another option that I rejected is to use a shared memory manager. I tend to avoid that because it constrains the caller to be a Delphi program.

To fill a stream from a buffer call `WriteBuffer`:

```
Stream.WriteBuffer(Buff^, BuffSize);
```

where `Buff` is a pointer to the buffer.

Comment: In #1 and #2, you have to change `OutBuff` to a `var` parameter so the DLL can alter the caller's input variable to point at the allocated memory.

Comment: @Remy it is a var parameter

Comment: It wasn't at the time I wrote that comment. You edited the question to add the `var`, instead of leaving the original question alone and mentioning the `var` in your answer.

Comment: @Remy It was like a clear mistake, contradicting text in the question, so I fixed it. The question was edited before my answer was posted, hence before your comment was posted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, How do I "populate the buffer"? after CoTaskMemAlloc.

Comment: You get the data, and write it to the buffer

Comment: I will accept this answer because it does answers my question. But I will use @Chris Rolliston solution which works really well for my needs.

Comment: Yes, an `IStream` is a clean and effective way to handle this.

Answer (score 8):

A slightly different approach is to wrap each memory stream up as a IStream, and pass around the resulting interface references. So, from the DLL's side:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.AxCtrls;

procedure DoProcess(InStream, OutStream: TStream);
begin
  //...do the actual processing here
end;

//wrapper export
procedure Process(AInStream: IStream; out AOutStream: IStream); safecall;
var
  InStream, OutStream: TStream;
begin
  InStream := TOleStream.Create(AInStream);
  try
    OutStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      DoProcess(InStream, OutStream);
      AOutStream := TStreamAdapter.Create(OutStream, soOwned);
    except
      OutStream.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    InStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Personally I like using safecall as well because it's an easy way to be exception-safe, but I guess that's a matter of taste.

**Edit**

A variant of the above is to have the caller provide both the stream to read **and** a stream to write to:

```
//wrapper export
procedure Process(AInStream, AOutStream: IStream); safecall;
var
  InStream, OutStream: TStream;
begin
  InStream := TOleStream.Create(AInStream);
  try
    OutStream := TOleStream.Create(AOutStream);
    try
      DoProcess(InStream, OutStream);
    finally
      OutStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The EXE side might then look something like this:

```
//wrapper import
type
  TDLLProcessProc = procedure(AInStream, AOutStream: IStream); safecall;

procedure Process(AInStream, AOutStream: TStream);
var
  InStream, OutStream: IStream;
  DLLProc: TDLLProcessProc;
  Module: HMODULE;
begin
  InStream := TStreamAdapter.Create(AInStream, soReference);
  OutStream := TStreamAdapter.Create(AOutStream, soReference);
  Module := LoadLibrary(MySuperLib);
  if Module = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    DLLProc := GetProcAddress(Module, 'Process');
    if @DLLProc = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
    DLLProc(InStream, OutStream);
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Module);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Isn't soOwned dangerous? How will the caller guaranty that the reference will be freed before FreeLibrary is called?

Comment: The caller will have to ensure that the returned `IStream` goes out of scope and gets released before the DLL is unloaded.  Which, if the `IStream` is used as a local variable at the site where `Process()` is called, is pretty much guaranteed (assuming the DLL is not unloaded in another thread). You would only have to worry about this if you start passing the `IStream` around to extend its lifetime for awhile.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, By setting `AOutStream` to `nil` before FreeLibrary?

Comment: @zig - see my edit. If that is genuinely a concern, just have the caller pass both the stream to read to and the stream to write to.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston, You have a typo `AInStream -> AOutStream` in `OutStream := TStreamAdapter.Create(AInStream, soReference);`

Comment: I'm going to use your solution which works very well for my needs. but I had to accept Davids answer because technically he did answer my question. P.S I had to set `OutStream.Position := 0` before using the output stream.

Answer (score 4):

> The InBuff is easy (I think). I pass TMemoryStream.Memory and TMemoryStream.Size.

Yes.

> Question is how do I allocate the OutBuff in the DLL, and the caller application can convert it back to TMemoryStream and later free that memory (By the caller application)?

Given the signature of the DLL function you showed, you would not allocate the memory in the DLL at all.  The caller has to allocate it.  The caller can call `Process()` once to get the needed size, then allocate it, then call `Process()` again to fill it.  This way, the caller is responsible for both allocating and freeing the memory.  For example:

```
procedure Process(InBuff: Pointer; InBuffSize: Integer; OutBuff: Pointer; var OutBuffSize: Integer); stdcall;
begin
  //...
  if (OutBuf <> nil) then
  begin
    // copy no more than OutBuffSize bytes into OutBuf, and then
    // update OutBuffSize with the number of bytes actually copied...
    Move(..., OutBuf^, ...);
    OutBuffSize := ...;
  end else begin
    // update OutBuffSize with the number of bytes needed for OutBuff...
    OutBuffSize := ...;
  end;
  //...
end;
```

```
var
  InStream: TMemoryStream;
  OutStream: TMemoryStream;
  BuffSize: Integer;
begin
  InStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // fill InStream as needed...

    BuffSize := 0;
    Process(InStream.Memory, InStream.Size, nil, BuffSize);

    OutStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      OutStream.Size := BuffSize;
      Process(InStream.Memory, InStream.Size, OutStream.Memory, BuffSize);
      // use OutStream as needed...
    finally
      OutStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    InStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you actually want the DLL to allocate the memory, you have to change the signature of your DLL function to make `OutBuff` be a `var` parameter.  You also have to export an additional function so the DLL can free the memory that the DLL allocated.  The benefit of this approach is that the caller would only have to call `Process()` once, and the DLL can decide how it wants to allocate and free the memory.  For example:

```
procedure Process(InBuff: Pointer; InBuffSize: Integer; var OutBuff: Pointer; var OutBuffSize: Integer); stdcall;
begin
  //...
  OutBuffSize := ...;
  GetMem(OutBuf, OutBuffSize);
  Move(..., OutBuf^, OutBuffSize);
  //...
end;

procedure FreeProcessBuff(InBuff: Pointer); stdcall;
begin
  FreeMem(InBuff);
end;
```

```
type
  TMemoryBufferStream = class(TCustomMemoryStream)
  public
    constructor Create(APtr: Pointer; ASize: NativeInt);
  end;

procedure TMemoryBufferStream.Create(APtr: Pointer; ASize: NativeInt);
begin
  inherited Create;
  SetPointer(APtr, ASize);
end;

...

var
  InStream: TMemoryStream;
  OutStream: TMemoryBufferStream;
  Buff: Pointer;
  BuffSize: Integer;
begin
  InStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    // fill InStream as needed...

    Buff := nil;
    BuffSize := 0;
    Process(InStream.Memory, InStream.Size, Buff, BuffSize);
    try
      OutStream := TMemoryBufferStream.Create(Buff, BuffSize);
      try
        // use OutStream as needed...
      finally
        OutStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      FreeProcessBuff(Buff);
    end;
  finally
    InStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `"The caller has to allocate it."` why? Only The DLL has that information **after** the process is done. The DLL does not know the output size in advance. Why would the DLL initially process just to know the the output size? and then process again...

Comment: @zig: a lot of custom APIs, and even the Win32 API itself, are designed to work that way in many cases. It makes memory allocation more flexible by allowing the caller to decide how it wants to manage the memory. Besides, my comment was in relation to the *original* DLL declaration that was shown (before David edited the question). If `OutBuff` is not a `var` parameter, the DLL cannot return a newly-allocated pointer to the caller's variable, so the caller has to allocate the memory and pass it in to the DLL instead.

Comment: I don't mind another DLL signature. `"If OutBuff is not a var parameter, the DLL cannot return a newly-allocated pointer to the caller's variable"` I did not know that. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful code. this made me understand how the DLL can allocate the memory and assign it to a TMemoryStream.