# Unexpected Thread behaviour calling Delphi DLL

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, dll, delphi-7

Continue from my other question:
[How do I pass and retrieve memory stream from my Application to/from DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211938/how-do-i-pass-and-retrieve-memory-stream-from-my-application-to-from-dll)

I have wrote the DLL using [`IStream` as input/output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34212440/3906993). The DLL uses `IXMLDocument` (which at first I thought was related to the follow problem)
Tested it, and it worked well in the main UI. Problems began when I was calling the DLL from a worker thread.

The DLL:

```
library MyDLL;

uses
  Windows,
  Variants,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  AxCtrls,
  ActiveX,
  XMLDoc,
  XMLIntf;

{$R *.res}    

procedure Debug(V: Variant);
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(VarToStr(V)));
end;

procedure DoProcess(InStream, OutStream: TStream);
var
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
begin
  InStream.Position := 0;
  Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  Doc.LoadFromStream(InStream);
  // plans to do some real work...
  OutStream.Position := 0;
  Debug('MyDLL DoProcess OK');
end;

function Process(AInStream, AOutStream: IStream): Integer; stdcall;
var
  InStream, OutStream: TStream;
begin
  try
    InStream := TOleStream.Create(AInStream);
    try
      OutStream := TOleStream.Create(AOutStream);
      try
        DoProcess(InStream, OutStream);
        Result := 0;
      finally
        OutStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      InStream.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Result := -1;
      Debug('MyDLL Error: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;

exports
  Process;

begin
end.
```

And my caller application:

```
implementation

uses
  ActiveX,ComObj;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Debug(V: Variant);
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar(VarToStr(V)));
end;

const
  MyDLL = 'MyDLL.dll';

{$DEFINE STATIC_DLL}
{$IFDEF STATIC_DLL}
function Process(AInStream, AOutStream: IStream): Integer; stdcall; external MyDLL;
{$ENDIF}

type
  // Dynamic
  TDLLProcessProc = function(AInStream, AOutStream: IStream): Integer; stdcall;

function DLLProcess(AInStream, AOutStream: TStream): Integer;
var
  InStream, OutStream: IStream;
  Module: HMODULE;
  DLLProc: TDLLProcessProc;
begin
  InStream := TStreamAdapter.Create(AInStream, soReference);
  OutStream := TStreamAdapter.Create(AOutStream, soReference);
{$IFDEF STATIC_DLL}
  Result := Process(InStream, OutStream); // Static
  Exit;
{$ENDIF}
  // Dynamic load DLL ...
  Module := LoadLibrary(MyDLL);
  if Module = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    DLLProc := GetProcAddress(Module, 'Process');
    if @DLLProc = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
    Result := DLLProc(InStream, OutStream);
  finally
    FreeLibrary(Module);
  end;
end;

type
  TDLLThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FFileName: string;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; AFileName: string);
    procedure Execute(); override;
  end;

constructor TDLLThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean; AFileName: string);
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FFileName := AFileName;
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

procedure TDLLThread.Execute;
var
  InStream, OutStream: TMemoryStream;
  RetValue: Integer;
begin
  try
    //CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      InStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        InStream.LoadFromFile(FFileName);
        OutStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          RetValue := DLLProcess(InStream, OutStream);
          Sleep(0);
          Debug('TDLLThread Result=> ' + IntToStr(RetValue));
          if RetValue = 0 then
          begin
            Debug('TDLLThread OK');
          end;
        finally
          OutStream.Free;
        end;
      finally
        InStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Debug('TDLLThread Error: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); // Test
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 5 do
    TDLLThread.Create(False, '1.xml');
end;
```

When running some tests I **sometimes** get Access Violations which even the exceptions blocks can't catch. And the program simply crashes with `Runtime error 216 at xxxxxxx` or `Invalid pointer operation`.

I have tried both static and dynamic DLL linking (figured **maybe** the dynamic linking has race condition in the LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary).

First I thought `IXMLDocument` was the main issue:

```
Doc := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
Doc.LoadFromStream(InStream);
```

This sometimes randomly failed with no apparent reason with:

> Invalid at the top level of the
>   document.

Or:

> A name was started with an invalid character.

I thought maybe it used some shared resources. but even **omitting these lines** caused AVs!

So the DLL is practically doing nothing special.
I also Don't see anything special which could infect `DLLMain`.

I have no Idea what is going on... Can someone suggest how to handle this situation? (Can someone reproduce this behavior?)

---

EDIT: I just wanted to add a related question (with similar `IsMultiThread` solution):
[Delphi DLL - thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677239/delphi-dll-thread-safe)

And some tips about `IsMultiThread`:
[IsMultiThread Variable](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/delphi-in-a/1565926595/re157.html)

Comment: I'd start by working out whether this is an issue with the threading, or an issue with the DLL. Move all the code out of the DLL and into the main executable. Do the errors remain. In that case it's a threading issue.

Comment: you're setting `FreeOnTerminate` before the thread object creation: `inherited Create(CreateSuspended)` shoud be the very 1st line in your constructor

Comment: @fantaghirocco That doesn't actually matter. It's certainly idiomatic to call the inherited constructor first. The thread won't be started until AfterConstruction. But it's not the issue.

Comment: Do you set `IsMultiThread := True` in the initialization your dll? If not, please add that and see what happens.

Comment: I wonder if MSXML COM object the topicstarter uses is thead-safe itself....

Comment: Why won't you use BPL instead of DLL?  BPL exactly was designed to pass complex objects between different modules

Comment: Because you didn't narrow it down, everyone is guessing. Please narrow this down. That's debugging 101.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan,I disagree. How more can I narrow this down? Only calling the DLL and only passing the streams causes AVs. I really have no idea how to "narrow it down" more than it is :/

Comment: @zig anything but char, integer, double, pointer to those  - is a complex object. Anything that deals with memory allocation is. Even the pointer to some constant becomes no more available as soon as DLL is unloaded

Comment: @Arioch'The, IStream is an interface. a pointer, look at GDI+ implementation for example. It's hardly a complex object.

Comment: @SebastianZ, How does `IsMultiThread` affect  a DLL in a multi-threaded application ? Can this really be the cure? Now I tried `IsMultiThread := True` and I cant reproduce the problems (Im not sure they are gone), and I don't understand why.

Comment: @Arioch BPL places severe constraints on host executables. Not necessary at all here. It's a COM interface.

Comment: I wanted to know if you could repro with just threads, or whether the DLL was key. You answered that now. Thanks. I've written up why IsMultiThread is needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it does, that both the plugin and host app should be written with the same Delphi/BCB version. However that is exactly what we already have here.

Comment: @zig interfaces are ref-counted (1) pointer with automatic memory management (2) and lots of features implemented by a complex library(3).

See, with BPL you would just pass the `TXMLDocument` as is, you would not have issues with `IsMultithreaded` and you would not make those tedious `GetProcAddress` and `TStreamAdapter` and such. 

That sure would impose a limitation mentioned above - but the one you already put upon yourself.

Comment: @Arioch No, the approach here has no such constraints. Do you understand the COM interfaces are compiler agnostic?

Comment: The interfaces are, with implementations it is not always that easy. Do you understand with BPL the topicstarter would not have the issue with `isMultiThreaded` ?

Comment: @Arioch'The, "BPL": The DLL will be used in C# host, and by older Delphi 5 application. If I were to use the same Delphi versions, I would not have used nor DLL/BPL in the first place. And personally, BPL=HELL :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The memory manager in Delphi has optimisations for single threaded use. These are enabled by default. If your code is multi-threaded then this optimisation needs to be disabled. Do that by setting `IsMultiThread` to `True`.

In a module that creates a Delphi thread, the framework sets `IsMultiThread` to `True` when a thread is created. In your program the threads are created by the host and so nothing in the library sets `IsMultiThread` to `True`. So you must do that explicitly in the DLL. In the main section of the library .dpr file write this:

```
begin
  IsMultiThread := True;
end.
```

Comment: Only one question: Can the LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary in my code cause race condition and NOT be thread safe?

Comment: No. `LoadLibrary` / `FreeLibrary` are threadsafe the way you use them. They have internal serialization. Loading and unloading a library over and again isn't really a great idea though. If you can avoid it, load once only.